# MVVM Pattern Query

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am learning WPF with MVVM Design pattern and trying to understand how to get some things done outside of the code behind. 
I have a login page, pictured below. 
[image]

I have a password control I took from http://www.wpftutorial.net/PasswordBox.html.

I would for now for the case of simple understanding, like to ask you if my code is in the right class/set correctly to abide to MVVVM regulations with seperation of concerns.

I currently have an if statement to check if the details match a name string and a password string. 
The code is in the code behind. I just wonder if this is correct with regards to MVVM. I wonder how you implement this in a ViewModel?

```
 private void OK_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     if (emp.Name == "ep" && emp.Password == "pass")
     {
         MessageBox.Show("namd and Pw accepted");
         //open new page
         var HomeScreen = new HomeScreen();
         HomeScreen.Show();
     }
     else
     {
         //deny access
         MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username and password");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of implementing the button click handler in the code behind, use an `ICommand` and bind it to the button's event in XAML.

Here is a really great tutorial that got me starting in MVVM:
[WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx)

**[Edited to add sample code]**

Heres a simple code example to do just what your example does, but in MVVM style and without any code-behind code *at all*.

1) Create a new WPF Solution, for this small example I named it simply "WpfApplication".

2) Edit the code of the automatically created `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApplication"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="234" Width="282">

  <!-- Create the ViewModel as the initial DataContext -->
  <Window.DataContext>
    <viewModel:MainWindowViewModel />
  </Window.DataContext>

  <Grid>
    <TextBox Height="23"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Margin="70,31,0,0"
             Name="textBox1"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Width="120"
             Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
    <TextBox Height="23"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             Margin="70,72,0,0"
             Name="textBox2"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Width="120"
             Text="{Binding Path=Password}" />
    <Label Content="Name"
           Height="28"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           Margin="22,29,0,0"
           Name="label1"
           VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Label Content="PW"
           Height="28"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           Margin="22,70,0,0"
           Name="label2"
           VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <Button Content="OK"
            Height="23"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Margin="70,119,0,0"
            Name="button1"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Width="120" 
            Command="{Binding Path=LoginCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding Path=.}"
            />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

(Ignore the Width, Height, Margin values, these are just copied & pasted from my designer and were quick & dirty adjusted to roughly look like your screenshot ;-) )

3) Create the Command class that will handle your log in logic. Note that I did not implement it as a RelayCommand like in Josh Smith's tutorial but it would be easy to modify the code accordingly:

```
      namespace WpfApplication
      {
        using System;
        using System.Windows;
        using System.Windows.Input;

        /// <summary>
        /// Checks the user credentials.
        /// </summary>
        public class LoginCommand : ICommand
        {

           /// <summary>
           /// Defines the method to be called when the command is invoked.
           /// </summary>
           /// <param name="parameter">Data used by the command.  If the command does not require data to be passed, this object can be set to null.</param>
           public void Execute(object parameter)
           {
              MainWindowViewModel viewModel = parameter as MainWindowViewModel;

              if (viewModel == null)
              {
                 return;
              }

              if (viewModel.Name == "ep" && viewModel.Password == "pass")
              {
                 MessageBox.Show("namd and Pw accepted");

                 //open new page
                 var HomeScreen = new HomeScreen();
                 HomeScreen.Show();
              }
              else
              {
                 //deny access
                 MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username and password");
              }
           }

           /// <summary>
           /// Defines the method that determines whether the command can execute in its current state.
           /// </summary>
           /// <returns>
           /// true if this command can be executed; otherwise, false.
           /// </returns>
           /// <param name="parameter">Data used by the command.  If the command does not require data to be passed, this object can be set to null.</param>
           public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
           {
              // Update this for your application's needs.
              return true;
           }

           public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
        }
     }
```

4) Now add the ViewModel that will communicate with the View and provide it the command interface and values:

```
    namespace WpfApplication
    {
       using System;
       using System.Collections.Generic;
       using System.ComponentModel;
       using System.Linq;
       using System.Text;
       using System.Windows.Input;

       /// <summary>
       /// TODO: Update summary.
       /// </summary>
       public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
       {    
          #region Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

          /// <summary>
          /// Occurs when a property value changes.
          /// </summary>
          public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

          /// <summary>
          /// Signal that the property value with the specified name has changed.
          /// </summary>
          /// <param name="propertyName">The name of the changed property.</param>
          protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
          {
             if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
             {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
             }
          }

          #endregion Implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged

          #region Backing Fields

          /// <summary>
          /// Gets or sets the value of Name.
          /// </summary>
          private string name;

          /// <summary>
          /// Gets or sets the value of Password.
          /// </summary>
          private string password;

          /// <summary>
          /// Gets or sets the value of LoginCommand.
          /// </summary>
          private LoginCommand loginCommand;

          #endregion Backing Fields

          #region Constructor

          /// <summary>
          /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="MainWindowViewModel"/> class.
          /// </summary>
          public MainWindowViewModel()
          {
             this.loginCommand = new LoginCommand();
          }

          #endregion Constructor

          #region Properties

          /// <summary>
          /// Gets or sets the name of the user.
          /// </summary>
          public string Name
          {
             get
             {
                return this.name;
             }

             set
             {
                if (this.name == value)
                {
                   return;
                }

                this.name = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Name");
             }
          }

          /// <summary>
          /// Gets or sets the user password.
          /// </summary>
          public string Password
          {
             get
             {
                return this.password;
             }

             set
             {
                if (this.password == value)
                {
                   return;
                }

                this.password = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Password");
             }
          }

          /// <summary>
          /// Gets or sets the command object that handles the login.
          /// </summary>
          public ICommand LoginCommand
          {
             get
             {
                return this.loginCommand;
             }

             set
             {
                if (this.loginCommand == value)
                {
                   return;
                }

                this.loginCommand = (LoginCommand)value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("LoginCommand");
             }
          }

          #endregion Properties
       }
    }
```

5) Finally, do not forget to add an additional Window `HomeScreen` that will be opened by the LoginCommand to the solution. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much, that makes things allot clearer. Does that mean, that whatever class I put the event handler into is the View model? And Any Methods I want to use with the view could go into the same class, and that would automatically be the viewModel? Thanks

Comment: @EPOColla: In your example I'd say yes. But EventHandlers and methods do not "automatically" make up the ViewModel. Ideally, you structure your classes so that the ViewModel is the only class to **directly** communicate with the View (some exceptions of this rule aside, e.g. Converters, Behaviors, ...).

Comment: This gives you the option to implement such handling in multiple way. For example, the ViewModel might provide a property that holds the `Command`. How you implement the `Command` ist up to you. You could do it with `RelayCommands` like in the tutorial or use a class that only implements the `ICommand` interface and reference that from the ViewModel. The beauty of MVVM is that the View never needs to know about HOW you handle `Click` event as long as you adhere to the interface.

Comment: My only issue is that the Execute() method is returning ViewModel as null so does not allow the values to pass. I do not understand, as the viewmodel should be passing string propertyName.

Comment: @EPOColla: Sorry, my fault. For some reason my posted XAML code did not display above. I edited my post, now you can see it. Note the `Binding` attributes on the `TextBoxes`, these add the data binding to the `ViewModel` and then it will contain the entered values when you enter the `Execute()` method. If you followed my steps above, a simple copy and paste to replace the original code in `MainWindow.xaml` should be enough to make it work now. :-)

Answer (score 2):

To implement that, you should bind the button's command like this -

```
<Button Content ="OK" Command = {Binding OKCommand} />
```

In your ViewModel, create an ICommand property for this binding like this -

```
public class MyViewModel() : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

ICommand _OKCommand;
public ICommand OKCommad
{
  get { return _OKCommand; }
  set { _OKCommand = value; PropertyChanged(OKCommad); }
}

public MyViewModel()
{
  this.OKCommand += new DelegateCommand(OKCommand_Execute);
}

public void OKCommand_Execute()
{
 // Code for button click here
}

}
```

Also note that for using this delegate command, you need to add reference to **Microsoft.Practices.Prism.dll**